# Jmeter Distributed Testing Issue

Tags: testing, jmeter, distributed, master-slave

Is there a way to synchronize "thread group runs" across slaves in Jmeter's distributed testing?

For example, Suppose my test plan has 2 thread groups and I run JMeter with 2 slaves.If one of the slaves finishes with the first thread group first, I want that particular slave to wait until the other slave gets done with the first thread group as well. Then I want them to proceed with the second one together!

Please help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think we have a straight forward method for this in JMeter. I assume you run your thread groups consecutively.

In this Case, Lets have one more thread group in between as given below. Let the thread count be 1. Create a Beanshell Sampler - You can do your own sync operation here. (create a file in a common location -  wait till total no of files = total no of slaves. it will almost make your sync accurate.

[image]

I think this approach will help!

**OR**

You can have 2 tests - First Thread Group in 1 JMX file and second thread group in second jmx file. Just call the second test once the first test is complete.